# Compile template before projecting the content. Dynamic projecting?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

In my project I am meeting several times the same problem, and yet, I have not been able to find a proper solution. I suspect it is all part of [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563) issue, but it sounds to me like a very normal use case.

Many times I have a component with a template such as: `<my-component><ng-content></ng-content></my-component>` where somewhere in the projected content is trying to get the instance of `<my-component>`. This simply does not work because the projected component gets resolved before `<my-component>` is compiled.

This makes impossible things like having custom form components while applying NgForm into them. Like I illustrate in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iB6iBUJIikh1J3OBfpTz). Which sounds pretty standard to me.

Is there anyway to workaround this, without having to explicitly apply `my-component` in the parent component?