# Programmatically add directive to ElementRef

Tags: angular

Is there any way to add a directive to an `ElementRef` from TypeScript? (or to fool Angular that there is a directive added)?

Comment: I recently answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388884/5011810). I think it's your case.

Comment: @chiffre I don't think so

Comment: This has been answered already https://stackoverflow.com/a/39565420/11719787, Simple answer is you can't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instantiate and apply directives programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563547/how-to-instantiate-and-apply-directives-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

[`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) actually doesn't reference an Angular component. Instead, it references a HTML DOM element like `HTMLDivElement`. They aren't real Angular elements, so directives can't be added to them.