# How to dynamically add a directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

How to dynamically add (<strike>inject</strike>) a directive into host?

I have a myTooltip directive and I would like to add mdTooltip directive to it's host. I have tried `setAttribute()` of `ElementRef.nativeElement`, but it doesn't create the mdTooltip directive.

mytooltip.directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-tooltip]',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'show()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'hide()',
  }
})
export class myTooltip {
  @Input('my-tooltip') message;

  constructor() { }

  show() {
    /* TODO: How to add md-tooltip directive to elementref (host)? */
  }

  hide() {
    /* TODO: remove md-tooltip directive from elementref (host) */
  }
}
```

By host I mean the element that has myTooltip directive:

```
<span my-tooltip="tooltip hint">Click here</span>
```

**The result** wouldn't change above html but on mouseenter it would have md-tooltip directive in span.

BTW, the reason I am using a wrapper and not directly md-tooltip is that I want to later modify the showing delay, hiding delay and customize material tooltip's behaviour in other means as well.

**Edit** Apparently adding directives dynamically is not currently supported :( I think this question should still be here in case it material team updates that

Comment: Have you tried `constructor(private tt:myTooltip) { console.log(tt); }`? Not sure if this works. What is "host" actually? `<span>` doesn't look like a component.

Comment: You're talking about "injecting" when you request a provider in constructor, but in this case I don't mean that. What I mean by injecting here is to have a possibility to insert a directive into an already rendered dom element, a span, in this case. You would do this in html like this `<span md-tooltip="tooltip hint">Click here</span>`, but now I'm looking for a programmatic way of doing it.

Comment: That's not named or related to injecting. Adding directives dynamically is currently not supported, only components can be added dynamically.

Comment: Yes, sorry for misleading naming. I'll change the title to something more describing. I also read something about adding components dynamically, but that didn't apply for adding directives dynamically, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That is a feature we are asking for in angular...read this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

A quick and dirty way to do it is to use:

I have a directive named `myHilite` (to highlight text), I also have a component named `MainComponent.ts`. In `MainComponent.ts` I added this line of code...

```
export class MainComponent {
    @HostBinding('attr.myHilite') myHiliteDirective = new myHilite();
}
```

If your directive requires parameters...

```
export class MainComponent {
    @HostBinding('attr.myHilite') myHiliteDirective = new myHilite(this.elementRef);
}
```

Your directive may need to execute code in one of its life cycle hooks, manually call the directive's lifecycle hook method in the parent component's lifecycle hook method like this...

```
export class MainComponent {
    //...code...

    ngOnInit(){
        this.myHiliteDirective.ngOnInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @btinoco one more thing I want to clear is `@HostBinding(attr.myDirective)` is in child component and `ngOnInit(){
    this.myHilite.ngOnInit();
}` is in parent's component. am I right?

Comment: @btinoco can you please change `myHilite` to `myHiliteDirective` or `myDirective` so that other readers should not be confused about this.

Comment: I edited the answer according to your comment, WasiF, but someone reverted it back to the original solution. Sorry.

Comment: This worked for me nicely. However, is there a way to remove the directive afterwards? Basically, I want to be able to dynamically apply or remove the directive.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this wouldn't work with directives that have hostlisteners as those would not be attached to the nativeElement, right?

Comment: @FelipeCenteno sorry I have not try that

Comment: @FelipeCenteno Seems like it wouldn't, but if lifecycle hooks are manual then initializing listeners on the directive can be done via a manual invoked method on the directve as well to initialize the listeners

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is coming in Angular 15.

See: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/directive-composition-api-in-angular-15/