# Attaching directives to dynamically added elements

Tags: angular

When you add an element with a directive to the DOM using another element's `ElementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML` property, the directive does not fire. How do I add an element to the DOM in a way that causes the directive to fire?

**Example**
If in my component I do something like the following:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _elem: ElementRef) { }    

    ngOnInit() {
        this._elem.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<span myDirective>Foo</span>';
    }

}
```

(This is a major simplification over my actual implementation, so let's ignore that this is bad practice for a second)

Then the `myDirective` that appears to be attached to the `<span>` will never actually run.

The question is: how do I get angular to recognize the new element with the directive so that it runs?

Comment: I have tried to do that before without success, it seems we do not have this possibility yet, but at least you can see a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive. Hope it helps!

Comment: You need to compile it. Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: @Maximus thanks for the link. Much more useful and informative than the docs.

Comment: @Campbell, you're welcome. If you find something unclear, you can post a clarification question here and I'll answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the fly compilation is removed from Angular 2+. Another Alternative loading components dynamically using **Dynamic Component Loader**. For this you have to change your existing implementation

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 1):

If you are nesting components inside each other, you need to look at:

- [Content Projection](https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/) and `<ng-content>`
- [@ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild)
- [@ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildrenDecorator)
- [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList).

Joshua Morony also did an [Ionic youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYvIjd8rCVQ) - covering these Angular features.