# Adding custom directive dynamically in the DOM in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

I am using Angular 10 version. I have created a custom directive 'FreeDraggingDirective'. I just want to attach this directive to a html element on runtime.

This is appModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgFlowchartModule } from 'projects/ng-flowchart/src/lib/ng-flowchart.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomStepComponent } from './custom-step/custom-step.component';
import { RouteStepComponent } from './custom-step/route-step/route-step.component';
import { NestedFlowComponent } from './nested-flow/nested-flow.component';
import { FormStepComponent } from './form-step/form-step.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { GroupComponent } from './group/group.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { FreeDraggingDirective } from './free-dragging.direcetive';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
AppComponent,
CustomStepComponent,
RouteStepComponent,
NestedFlowComponent,
FormStepComponent,
GroupComponent,FreeDraggingDirective
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
NgFlowchartModule,
FormsModule,
MatMenuModule,
MatDialogModule,
MatTooltipModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatToolbarModule,
MatIconModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
ToastrModule.forRoot(), // ToastrModule added
],
exports: [
FormsModule,
FreeDraggingDirective,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this my Directive

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  ContentChild,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnDestroy,
} from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { max, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '.appFreeDragging',
})
export class FreeDraggingDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private element: HTMLElement;

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  // @ContentChild(FreeDraggingHandleDirective)
  // handle: FreeDraggingHandleDirective;

  handleElement: HTMLElement;

  private readonly DEFAULT_DRAGGING_BOUNDARY_QUERY = '.ngflowchart-canvas';
  @Input() boundaryQuery = this.DEFAULT_DRAGGING_BOUNDARY_QUERY;
  draggingBoundaryElement: HTMLElement | HTMLBodyElement;
  handle: any;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.draggingBoundaryElement = (this.document as Document).querySelector(
      'body'
    );
    if (!this.draggingBoundaryElement) {
      throw new Error(
        "Couldn't find any element with query: " + this.boundaryQuery
      );
    } else {
      this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      this.handleElement =
        this.handle?.elementRef?.nativeElement || this.element;
      this.initDrag();
    }
  }

  initDrag(): void {
    const dragStart$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.handleElement, 'mousedown');
    const dragEnd$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.document, 'mouseup');
    const drag$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.document, 'mousemove').pipe(
      takeUntil(dragEnd$)
    );

    let initialX: number,
      initialY: number,
      currentX = 0,
      currentY = 0;

    let dragSub: Subscription;

    const minBoundX = this.draggingBoundaryElement.offsetLeft;
    const minBoundY = this.draggingBoundaryElement.offsetTop;

    const maxBoundX =
      minBoundX +
      this.draggingBoundaryElement.offsetWidth -
      this.element.offsetWidth;
    const maxBoundY =
      minBoundY +
      this.draggingBoundaryElement.offsetHeight -
      this.element.offsetHeight;

    const dragStartSub = dragStart$.subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
      initialX = event.clientX - currentX;
      initialY = event.clientY - currentY;
      this.element.classList.add('free-dragging');

      dragSub = drag$.subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const x = event.clientX - initialX;
        const y = event.clientY - initialY;
        currentX = x;
        currentY = y;

        this.element.style.transform =
          'translate3d(' + currentX + 'px, ' + currentY + 'px, 0)';
      });
    });

    const dragEndSub = dragEnd$.subscribe(() => {
      initialX = currentX;
      initialY = currentY;
      this.element.classList.remove('free-dragging');
      if (dragSub) {
        dragSub.unsubscribe();
      }
    });

    this.subscriptions.push.apply(this.subscriptions, [
      dragStartSub,
      dragSub,
      dragEndSub,
    ]);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.subscriptions.forEach((s) => s?.unsubscribe());
    }
    }
```

so the problem is when try to add this directive on html this is working.

```
<div class="outerContent appFreeDragging" > 
   <!-- content inside here is draggable -->
</div>
```

But when achieve the same by adding it dynamically it's not working.

```
let outerContent = document.querySelector('outerContent');
outerContent.classList.add('appFreeDragging');
```

The above code is creating a class in the DOM but the directive is not working. Is there any possible way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 | How to dynamically inject a directive when click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446982/angular-4-how-to-dynamically-inject-a-directive-when-click)

Comment: @AbhishekSingh In this solution they already have the element in the HTML, but I am trying to create a new element dynamically and trying to add a directive dynamically.

Comment: You should NOT use vanillaJS to create your elements, but rather use Angular for it. Please be more specific about your code and your goal here.

Comment: I have edited the post and provided more info now, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

definately it won't work, angular bind directive on component load