# Send a preset value to a directive without having to wait

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm having a huge pain with this and I believe there is nothing else I can google.

I've got an input field that when the component loads has a preset value. The value is the name of the group so is different on different groups:

Basically this.el.nativeElement does not exist on load and is in a different lifecycle to ngOnInit. I can resolve this with a setTimeout as this waits for the value to exist, but is a guess.

```
 <input type="text" 
        id="name"
        formControlName="name"
        appPlaceholder
        required>
```

I have a Directive which needs to know if there is a preset value on the input. As sometimes there isn't one due to creating a group.

The problem that I am having is I have to use setTimeout to wait 1 second for the component to load the value on NgInit:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.activeStateCheck(this.el.nativeElement);
}, 1000);
```

This isn't really an ideal solution and I would prefer for the attribute directive to wait for the data to be loaded in the input and then run my function.

Things I've looked at:

- I've looked into inputs without much success
- I've looked into subscribing to a valueChange but this seems to only happen when the
  user actually changes the input.
- And the setTimeout I've already
  spoken about.
- Also used a lot of the lifeCycle hooks like ngAfterViewInit.

Looking for a good example and an explanation why I need to wait for the data to be shown instead of just getting the nativeElement straight away.

Comment: Yeah Angular 5 we are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the solution on this: 
[How to dynamically add a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive)

It seems very similar to what you need.