# How to add directive on loaded HTML in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic3, angular5

After HTML loaded I can select any HTML element using `ElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector()` so how to apply directive on selected element?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and a ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Share what you have done so that it helps people to understand your issue and help you out.

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular 5, you are not able to add directives to an element dynamically. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive) is potentially the same or a related question.