# Angular 7 - Add directive dynamically

Tags: angular, angular7

```html
<input  {{field.validatorDirective}} 
        class="form-control" 
        [ngClass]="{ 'border-danger': hasErrors }" 
        (keyup)="callback()" 
        [formControlName]="field.key" 
        [id]="field.key"
        [type]="field.type" 
        [placeholder]="field.placeholder" 
        [value]="field.value">
```

`field` has all the content required but I'd like to dynamically add the directive name to be used.

It is currently added as a `string` as `field.validatorDirective`

This has the error

> TextComponent.html:2 ERROR DOM Exception: Failed to execute
>   'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{field.validatorDirective}}' is not a
>   valid attribute name.

My Directive has the selector `usernameValidator`

Comment: {{field?.validatorDirective}} try like this ?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: I have added what the directive name is `usernameValidator` this is being passed through as `field.validatorDirective`

Comment: This might help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive/43752424

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can't do that. I did try with `[attr.directiveSelector]="condition"` but doesn't work with that as well.

A **workaround**(if you're interested in one) would be to have two inputs with an `*ngIf` on both. Something like this:

```
<input  directive1
    *ngIf="condition1"
        class="form-control" 
        [ngClass]="{ 'border-danger': hasErrors }" 
        (keyup)="callback()" 
        [formControlName]="field.key" 
        [id]="field.key"
        [type]="field.type" 
        [placeholder]="field.placeholder" 
        [value]="field.value">

<input directive2
    *ngIf="condition2"
    class="form-control" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'border-danger': hasErrors }" 
    (keyup)="callback()" 
    [formControlName]="field.key" 
    [id]="field.key"
    [type]="field.type" 
    [placeholder]="field.placeholder" 
    [value]="field.value">
```