# Angular - automatically add directive to all elements with a given class

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

Is it possible to add a directive programmatically to all elements in a component with a given class name, possibly using

`document.getElementsByClassName("btn")`

I want to add the `matRipple` directive to all elements that use the `btn` class without requiring our team to manually add the directive to every element.

Or is there another way I am missing to apply an Angular Material directive to elements of a given class or tag name (e.g. `button`)

Note that this is intended for legacy apps where we do not want to switch them all to `mat-button`s.  The directive works fine, but I am looking for a way to make it easier for our devs.

Comment: Why not just do search and replace once?

Comment: I was looking for a piece of JS i could add so that my devs would not need to do that.  Just curious, as that would be the obvious solution but require them to do something.

Answer (score 3):

> Or is there another way I am missing to apply an Angular Material directive to elements of a given class or tag name (e.g. button)

Yes, you may declare a selector to be based on a tag, attribute, class and so on. For a class, you would define it as: `'.class'`.

You may find all options on the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#options)

Comment: This is good to know, but would require me to make code changes to the directive itself.  While I could do that for my own directives, I don't want to edit Angular Material's source code.  Unless I misunderstand...

Comment: You're right @Steve. Missed that you were using a third party directive. I've tried to create a custom directive to wrap matRipple directive and insert it programatically, but it seems not to be possible so far. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752424/6481438) points to a github request for that and provides an alternative (not sure if this is suitable for this use case). Also, should I delete this answer so?

Comment: No, your answer might help someone else.  Thanks for the link!