# Adding dynamically cdkDrag directive into a generated component

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I have a generated div in which I'd like to add the drag&drop.

In HTML, it is something like this:

```
 (div) cdkdrag ... (/div)
```

But as my component is generated, i'd like to do something like that but don't know how:

```
let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
"myDiv.cdkDrag...?????"
```

If anyone know if it's possible and how ?

```
HTML way: <div cdkdrag >...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest an easier option would be to have your template and use conditional `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` statements to construct/destruct. That way you will already have the correct attributes and have added checks during compile.

i.e

```
  <div *ngIf="shouldShowDragElement" cdkDrag>...</div>
```

or

```
  <div *ngFor="let element of generatedElementsList" cdkDrag>...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks chris, but unfortunately it could not work in my case because i have to create my dragable div in another generated component:

let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
"myDiv.cdkDrag...?????"
AnotherGeneratedDIV.appendChild(myDraggableDIV)

The other way i've find for the moment is to create my div in the html and to move it in my generated div. But i will be better if i could done all in the ts dynamically.

Comment: Ok, in that case you might want to take a look at the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive/43752424