# Dynamically add *ngFor to HTML element

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create the following HTML element in my app.component.ts file:

```
 <a *ngFor="let ver of versionList">{{ver}}</a>
```

The issue I'm running into is adding the `*ngFor` to the element. I've tried using:

```
const a = this.renderer.createElement('a');
this.renderer.setProperty(a, '*ngFor', 'let ver of versionList');
```

and

```
const a = this.renderer.createElement('a');
this.renderer.setAttribute(a, '*ngFor', 'let ver of versionList');
```

with no luck. I haven't been able to find any references for dynamically adding `*ngFor` in the documentation so I'm wondering if this is possible?

renderer is declared in constructor as: `private renderer: Renderer2`
Angular version: 8.2.2

Comment: Can check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: All you need to do is to dynamically add elements to the array you are iterating over i.e. `versionList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as `*ngFor` should be compiled by Angular. But why do you need that?
Usually it is enough to add it to HTML and set `*ngIf="versionList && versionList.length > 0"`

Comment: The goal is to have a single .html file (app.component.html) where I can add and remove html elements as they are needed instead of using `*ngIf` or hiding them. I've been working with angular for about 3 weeks so I apologize if this was a silly question. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: This would work.  Note that you cannot have *ngFor and *ngIf on the same element, so you can wrap it in an <ng-container *ngIf="" > <a *ngFor=""> </a></ng-container>\