# Angular dynamic #

Tags: angular

In Angular you can use the # to identify a directive like this:

```
<div #actualTarget></div>
```

I need to make mine dynamic like this:

```
<div #{{l + '-' + n}}></div>
```

What's the correct way to do this?

```
 <div class="list-cont shadow" *ngFor="let cat of categories; let l = index">
 ...
  <ul class="responder" *ngFor="let responder of cat.bidderResponses; let n = index">

   <li>
    #
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to make it dynamic?

Comment: cause its in a couple of loops that are building the elements dynamically

Comment: Can you show these loops and how you want to use the template reference variables? I doubt that you need them to be dynamic. You can probably use `#actualTarget`.

Comment: i added more code above

Comment: I don't see the `div` with the template reference variable, can you show it? And what will you do with it? Why don't you just use `#actualTarget`?

Comment: see the <li> that's it

Answer (score 2):

There is no dynamic reference variable in `Angular Template syntax`.

Inside a structual directive like `ngFor` your template is nested in a seperate scope.
So you could easily use it like:

```html
 <div class="list-cont shadow" *ngFor="let cat of categories; let l = index">
 ...
  <ul class="responder" *ngFor="let responder of cat.bidderResponses; let n = index">

   <li #myReference>

   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

> A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element
>   within a template. It can also refer to a directive (which contains a
>   component), an element, TemplateRef, or a web component.

You could pass variables to your directive using the [@Input()](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator and [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) and do some validation inside the directive.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  colors: string[] = [
    'yellow',
    'Blue',
    'Red',
    'Grey'
  ]
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let color of colors">
  <p appHighlight [highlightColor]="color"> {{ color }} </p>
</div>
```

**highlight.directive.ts**

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() highlightColor: string

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

working example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9k5uhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.directive.ts)

There is also an open question at the angular Githup and a workaround for adding directives to host elements in component declaration:

[How to dynamically add a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

Maybe you can explain more exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Wouldn’t the make every generated element in for loop have the same reference variable?

Comment: Yes, but it will be in a seperated scope, so there will be no conflicts. You should explain your goal because i think u are using the wrong pattern for your Problem.