# How to add default properties of input tag dynamically?

Tags: html, angular

I wanted to append the properties of input tag like id, name and value to be added dynamically to the HTML.

<input [id]="cid" [name]="cname" [value]="cvalue"/>

cid, cname and cvalue are available from component in ngOnInit() call.

would this be suffice or is there any other way?

Comment: Just try it and see what happens ?

Comment: i think what are you looking for is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831170/how-to-add-attribute-dynamically-in-angular

Comment: @temp_user : I'm trying this for radio button, the behavior is not as expected. If I select on radio button the other is selecting.

Comment: @RobinHood - that was not for the default attributes.

Comment: @KrishnaAtmakur look into how radio buttons work then. Hint : it has to do with the `name` attribute.

Comment: all the radio buttons must have same name then it will unique selection

Comment: The IDs are unique and name is same for all the radio button, the behavior is changing somehow when I add the attributes dynamically. That's my problem.