# Can I apply directive to nativeElement programmatically(dynamically)?

Tags: angular

**For example:**

```
<button>Click<button>
```

**into**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent">Click<button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically add a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive)

Comment: In this example directive applies to component but I need to DOMElement