# Use MatTooltip with host Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working with Angular 15.1 & Angular Material 15.1 and I need to use MatTooltip directive with the host component. I know I can create a wrapper and use tooltip attribute - but I need a solution with the host component.

I tried to use MatTooltip like that:

```
 host: {
    '[attr.matTooltip]': 'some text',
  }
```

and also with ViewContainerRef, createComponent method and @HostListener, but none of the options did work out

Comment: Did you try `@HostBinding`? This question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, cause I wanted to use MatTooltip exactly, not the custom directive. But it's not possible at the moment, as i found out from the accepted answer

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found an answer on my own, maybe someone will need this too. I will share code pieces below.**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: `
   
    <div>test</div>
  `,
  providers: [MatTooltip],
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
})

...

constructor(
    private readonly _tooltip: MatTooltip,
  ) {}

...

@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter(): void {
    this._tooltip.message = 'your message';
    this._tooltip.show();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave(): void {
    this._tooltip.hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in Angular v15 you can use [Directive composition API](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: 'test.html',
  hostDirectives: [{
    directive: MatTooltip,
    inputs: [...],
    outputs: [...],
  }],
})
export class TestComponent { }
```

Comment: I've got an error "Host directive MatTooltip must be standalone"

Comment: check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9tczmy?file=src/app/tooltip-overview-example.ts)

Comment: can I do that without creating custom directive? I want use [matTooltip] without any additional directives

Comment: Not until the angular material project migrates to standalone api

Comment: I can confirm that what @MehdiShakeri has shared is in fact the solution.

Comment: The input in the stackblitz does not seem to be necessary, it works without as well. But thanks for the solution!