# dynamically create element with directive Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-changedetection

I am trying to dynamically create an element in angular that has a directive. the directive in question is nbButton and applies certain classes to the element.
the button is rendered at runtime by dataTable, but unfortunately the classes are not applied and I am not finding a way to force the element to be updated.

datatable configurations are as follows:

```js
const conf: any = {
      paging: true,
      ...
      buttons: [
        {
            text: 'filter',
            action:() => {
                sidebarService.toggle();
            },
            attr:  {
              nbButton: '',
            }
        },
        ...
      ]
  }

this.categoryTable.DataTable(conf);
```

the attribute is inserted correctly into the element, but the directive is not executed not even by running change ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() or similar.

[image]

in the example above, "foo" is a button built outside of dataTable with directive, "Filtra e cerca" is a datatable's button to which I manually added the first classes, "Aggiungi nuovo" and "Azioni" are elements with the directive applied but without classes

some idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instantiate and apply directives programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563547/how-to-instantiate-and-apply-directives-programmatically)

Comment: As per above link, directives can't be applied outside of html templates. You can dynamically create components using factory, but for directives that's not possible.

Comment: @HostBinding? https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding